# Python constructor and default value

Tags: python, constructor, default-value

Somehow, in the Node class below, the `wordList` and `adjacencyList` variable is shared between all instances of Node.

```
>>> class Node:
...     def __init__(self, wordList = [], adjacencyList = []):
...         self.wordList = wordList
...         self.adjacencyList = adjacencyList
... 
>>> a = Node()
>>> b = Node()
>>> a.wordList.append("hahaha")
>>> b.wordList
['hahaha']
>>> b.adjacencyList.append("hoho")
>>> a.adjacencyList
['hoho']
```

Is there any way I can keep using the default value (empty list in this case) for the constructor parameters but to get both `a` and `b` to have their own `wordList` and `adjacencyList` variables?

I am using python 3.1.2.

Answer (score 188, accepted):

Mutable default arguments don't generally do what you want. Instead, try this:

```
class Node:
     def __init__(self, wordList=None, adjacencyList=None):
        if wordList is None:
            self.wordList = []
        else:
             self.wordList = wordList 
        if adjacencyList is None:
            self.adjacencyList = []
        else:
             self.adjacencyList = adjacencyList
```

Comment: These can also be one-liners: `self.wordList = wordList if wordList is not None else []`, or, slightly less safe, `self.wordList = wordList or []`.

Comment: This is considered the Pythonic way, but I prefer krousey's way because "special cases aren't special enough".

Comment: @JoshBleecherSnyder I couldn't put my finger on it, what makes the latter less safe than the former?

Comment: @markdsievers many things other than `None` evaluate to `False` (e.g. `False`, `0`, `""`, `{}`, `()`, objects that specify `__nonzero__()`).  The former is specific: `None` is the only special object that triggers defaulting to `[]`. The latter will replace any false-y object with `[]`.

Comment: Michael J. Barber's contribution is correct - but no explanation is offered. The reason for this behavior is that the default argument is bound at function definition, not runtime. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-which-scope-is-the-mutable-default-argument-in

Comment: So, is this a bug? This behavior is quite counterintuitive.

Comment: @sharshofski: It's a terrible design decision, and I don't know of any other language that handles defaults like this, but it's not officially considered a bug.

Answer (score 38):

Let's illustrate what's happening here:

```
Python 3.1.2 (r312:79147, Sep 27 2010, 09:45:41) 
[GCC 4.4.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> class Foo:
...     def __init__(self, x=[]):
...         x.append(1)
... 
>>> Foo.__init__.__defaults__
([],)
>>> f = Foo()
>>> Foo.__init__.__defaults__
([1],)
>>> f2 = Foo()
>>> Foo.__init__.__defaults__
([1, 1],)
```

You can see that the default arguments are stored in a tuple which is an attribute of the function in question. This actually has nothing to do with the class in question and goes for any function. In python 2, the attribute will be `func.func_defaults`.

As other posters have pointed out, you probably want to use `None` as a sentinel value and give each instance it's own list.

Answer (score 28):

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, wordList=None adjacencyList=None):
        self.wordList = wordList or []
        self.adjacencyList = adjacencyList or []
```

Answer (score 20):

I would try:

```
self.wordList = list(wordList)
```

to force it to make a copy instead of referencing the same object.