# Shallow copy instead of new object in Python

Tags: python, oop, inheritance, deep-copy

I'm trying to create a new object of a class inside this same class, however instead of creating a whole new object it simply creates a new reference to the same object I'm currently working in.

So if I change the value of one object, it changes the value in the other as well - even though I probably should have 2 completely different objects.

Using the `copy.deepcopy()` method fixes the issue with the reference, but I guess that it should work differently as well.

How does my code behave in this specific implementation? Is there a reason for it to create a shallow copy of the same object even though the code probably should create a new instance of it?

This is a slightly reduced code snippet:

```
class Vec4():
    def __init__(self, x = 0, y = 0, z = 0, w = 0):
        self.values = [x,y,z,w]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.values[0]) + ' ' + str(self.values[1]) + ' ' + str(self.values[2]) + ' ' + str(self.values[3])

    def setValue(self, index, value):
        self.values[index] = value


    def scalar(self, vector):
        """returns the result of the scalar multiplication"""
        result = 0
        for u in range(4):
            result += self.values[u] * vector.values[u]
        return result




class Matrix4():
    def __init__(self, row1 = Vec4(), row2 = Vec4(), row3 = Vec4(), row4 = Vec4()):
        self.m_values = [row1,row2,row3,row4]
        self.trans_values = [Vec4(),Vec4(),Vec4(),Vec4()]
        self.set_transp_matrix()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.m_values[0].__str__() + '\n' + self.m_values[1].__str__() + '\n' + self.m_values[2].__str__() + '\n' + self.m_values[3].__str__()

    def setIdentity(self):

        identity = Matrix4(Vec4(1,0,0,0),
                       Vec4(0,1,0,0),
                       Vec4(0,0,1,0),
                       Vec4(0,0,0,1))
        for i in range(4):
            for j in range(4):
                self.m_values[i].values[j] = identity.m_values[i].values[j]

    def set_transp_matrix(self):
         for t in range(4):
            for s in range(4):
                self.trans_values[t].values[s] = self.m_values[s].values[t]

    def get_trans_matrix(self):
        return self.trans_values[0].__str__() + '\n' + self.trans_values[1].__str__() + '\n' + self.trans_values[2].__str__() + '\n' + self.trans_values[3].__str__()

    def mulM(self, m):

        print(self, "\n")
        matrixResult = Matrix4()
        print(matrixResult, "\n")
        for row in range(4):  # rows of self
            for element in range(4):
                value = self.m_values[row].scalar(m.trans_values[element])
                matrixResult.m_values[row].setValue(element, value)
        return matrixResult


class ScaleMatrix(Matrix4):

    def __init__(self, m_scale = Vec4(1,1,1), *args, **kwargs):
        super(ScaleMatrix, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.m_scale = m_scale
        self.update()

    def getScale(self):
        """Returns the scale vector, only x, y and z are relevant"""
        return self.m_scale

    def setScale(self, v):
        """Sets the scale vector, only x, y and z are relevant"""
        self.m_scale = v
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        """Calculates the scale matrix"""

        self.setIdentity()

        for i in range(3):
            self.m_values[i].values[i] = self.getScale().values[i]

        return self


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Simple Constructor and Print
    a = Vec4(1,2,3,4)
    b = Vec4(5,6,7,8)
    c = Vec4(9,10,11,12)
    d = Vec4(13,14,15,16)


    A = Matrix4(a, b, c, d)
    D = ScaleMatrix()
    D.setScale(Vec4(3, 4, 5, 1))

    print(D.mulM(A))
```

The issue is in the class `Matrix4`, method `mulM()` where `matrixResult = Matrix4()` should create a whole new instance of `Matrix4()` (where all values of `Vec4()` should be `0`) instead of simply copying the `self` object. The output of `print` shows the following:

```
3 0 0 0
0 4 0 0
0 0 5 0
0 0 0 1 

3 0 0 0
0 4 0 0
0 0 5 0
0 0 0 1 

3 6 51 672
20 64 508 6688
45 140 1170 15340
13 40 334 4396
```

So the second matrix should not be equal to the first one.
However, the issue does not occur if I create a normal `Matrix4()` object instead of the `ScaleMatrix()` object which extends `Matrix4()` in the very end of the code snippet above.

Python v.3.6.4

Comment: While *shadow* copy sounds super cool, are you sure you don't mean *shallow* copy?

Comment: Yep, you are right. Thank you for the correction, I'll edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python evaluates the default parameters when a function is defined. When you define:

```
class Matrix4():
    def __init__(self, row1 = Vec4() ...
```

you create a `Vec4` instance, and this instance will now be used as default value each time this `__init__` method gets called.

The first time you create a `Matrix4` instance, `__init__` will execute, and this instance gets refered to by the name `row1`

Then you have:

```
    self.m_values = [row1,row2,row3,row4]
```

So this instance is now refered to by self.m_values[0].

Later, in `ScaleMatrix.update`, you update this `Vec4` instance:

```
for i in range(3):
            self.m_values[i].values[i] = self.getScale().values[i]
```

The next time you will call `Matrix4.__init__` without parameters, the default value will be used, and this is the `Vec4` that you just updated.

You have a similar behaviour when you use an empty list as default parameter, see [“Least Astonishment” and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument)
.

The usual way to avoid this problem is to avoid using mutable objects as default parameters. You could do:

```
class Matrix4():
    def __init__(self, row1 = None, row2 = None, row3 = None, row4 = None):
        if row1 is None:
            row1 = Vec4()
        if row2 is None:
            row2 = Vec4()
        if row3 is None:
            row3 = Vec4()
        if row4 is None:
            row4 = Vec4()
        self.m_values = [row1,row2,row3,row4]
        self.trans_values = [Vec4(),Vec4(),Vec4(),Vec4()]
        self.set_transp_matrix()
```

which gives as output:

```
3 0 0 0
0 4 0 0
0 0 5 0
0 0 0 1 

0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 

3 6 9 12
20 24 28 32
45 50 55 60
13 14 15 16
```

Comment: Thank you for your descriptive explanation! I do understand my issue a lot better now

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Python constructor and default value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4841782/8033585) and ["Least Astonishment" and the Mutable Default Argument](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/8033585) Your issue is fundamentally similar to the issue described in the above linked issues.

Also, when declaring a class, make it a subclass of `object`:

```
class Vec4(object):
class Matrix4(object):
```

Finally, to address your particular issue, remove defaults for the initializer. For example, do something like this:

```
class Matrix4():
    def __init__(self, row1=None, row2=None, row3=None, row4=None):
       if row1 is None:
           row1 = Vec4()
       if row2 is None:
           row2 = Vec4()
       if row3 is None:
           row3 = Vec4()
       if row4 is None:
           row4 = Vec4()
       self.m_values = [row1,row2,row3,row4]
```

Same goes for the default of `ScaleMatrix` argument `m_scale`:

```
class ScaleMatrix(Matrix4):
    def __init__(self, m_scale = Vec4(1,1,1), *args, **kwargs):
```