# Drawing 2 cards each for player and dealer ends up both dealer and player having the same 4 cards

Tags: python, blackjack

I have a Hand() class, with an attribute .user_hand which is a list of their cards, and have created 2 instances for dealer and player. The .draw() method should move the top card to the .user_hand of its respective player but it seems to move it to both players instead.

```
class Card:

def __init__(self, suit, rank):
    self.suit = suit
    self.rank = rank

def __str__(self):
    return self.rank + ' of ' + self.suit

def __int__(self):
    global list_of_ranks
    return list_of_ranks[self.rank]


class Deck:

def __init__(self, deck_cards=[]):
    self.deck_cards = deck_cards
    for suit in list_of_suits:
        for rank in list_of_ranks:
            self.deck_cards.append(Card(suit,rank))

def shuffle(self):
    random.shuffle(self.deck_cards)


class Hand:

def __init__(self, user_hand=[], turn=True, blackjack=False, win=False):
    self.blackjack = blackjack
    self.user_hand = user_hand
    self.blackjack = blackjack
    self.win = win

def draw(self):
    self.user_hand.append(new_deck.deck_cards[0])
    new_deck.deck_cards.remove(new_deck.deck_cards[0])

def show_hand(self):
    print('\n\nDealer\'s hand:')
    for x in dealer_hand.user_hand:
        print(x)
    print('\nYour hand:')
    for x in new_hand.user_hand:
        print(x)
    print('Total value: {}'.format(calc(self.user_hand)))
```

...

```
new_hand.draw()
dealer_hand.draw()
new_hand.draw()
dealer_hand.draw()

new_hand.show_hand()
```

my result:

```
Dealer's hand:
Queen of Spades
Six of Diamonds
Nine of Clubs
Six of Spades

Your hand:
Queen of Spades
Six of Diamonds
Nine of Clubs
Six of Spades
Total value: 31
```

Comment: It would be good if you also give the code for the deck. The element `new_deck` doesn't seem to be defined in `.draw()` method.

Comment: @Mathieu I have updated it

Comment: Your `Hand` class references several external (presumably global) variables (i.e. `new_deck`, `new_hand` and `dealer_hand`). This breaks encapsulation and makes it difficult to debug / predict the expected behavior. Especially as you still haven't shown the code where those variables are defined/created.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting case which was already mentioned in many articles, eg. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4841782/python-constructor-and-default-value).

Your init with default array is the problem. Any time you call `draw()` method from different objects you actually fill the same array.

```
class Hand:

def __init__(self, user_hand=[], turn=True, blackjack=False, win=False):
...
```

You could solve it like this:

```
class Hand:

def __init__(self, user_hand=None, turn=True, blackjack=False, win=False):
    if user_hand is None:
        self.user_hand = []
    else:
         self.user_hand = user_hand
...
```