# Confussion on nested dataclasses

Tags: python

Consider the following class:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class Test:
    result: int = None
    
@dataclass
class Test2:
    nested = Test()
    result: int = None
    

class Mainthing:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value
        self.results = Test2()
        
    def Main(self):
        value = self.value
        self.results.result = value   
        self.results.nested.result = value
```

If I make an instance of the class:

```
x = Mainthing(1)
```

And call the `Main()` function:

```
x.Main()
```

The results are as they should be,

```
x.results.result
Out[0]: 1
x.results.nested.result
Out[1]: 1
```

If I then delete the instance

```
del x
```

and make it again

```
x = Mainthing(1)
```

The `x.results.result` is now None as i would expect, but the nested is not

```
x.results.nested.result
Out[]: 1
```

Why is that?

Comment: `nested = Test()` creates a *class* attribute that is a specific `Test` instance. It is never recreated. Use a factory if you want a new attribute per instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a type annotation, `nested` is a class attribute, unused by `@dataclass`, which means it's shared between all instances of `Test2` (`dataclasses.fields(Test2)` won't report it, because it's not an instance attribute).

Making it an instance attribute alone, with:

```
nested: Test = Test()
```

might *seem* like it works (it does make it a field), but it's got [the same problem using mutable default arguments has everywhere](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4841782/364696); it ends up being a *shared* default, and mutations applied through one instance change the value shared with everyone else.

If you want to use a new `Test()` for each instance, make it a `field` with a `default_factory`, adding `field` to the imports from `dataclasses`, and changing the definition to, e.g.:

```
nested: Test = field(default_factory=Test)
```

If you always want to create your own instance, never accept one from the user, make it:

```
nested: Test = field(default_factory=Test, init=False)
```

so the generated `__init__` does not accept it (accepting only `result`).

Comment: Perfect. Thank you!